# Using DTED data publishing from GeoServer with Arcgis Runtime in C#

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I'm publishing GeoServer raster layers with WMTS. Only one of these layers consists of DTED data. I am trying to create a 3D world model with this data. I can use the data published from GeoServer on the map. But I can't provide terrain. As a result of my research, I think that Arcgis Runtime has such a service. There is no problem using local DTED data or DTED data published with Arcgis Server, but is there an API to use DTED data published from GeoServer in Arcgis Runtime?

Comment: Are you asking how to publish data from GeoServer as DTED? or how to publish DTED data in GeoServer?

Comment: @IanTurton No, I can already publish DTED data. But how can I use this published data as terrain surface with Arcgis Runtime?

Comment: Sorry, you'll need an arcgis expert for that